# Why doesn't sh with errexit work with a command list?

Tags: error-handling, sh

If I run the following shell script as a normal user, it aborts at line three as expected:

```
set -o errexit

echo foo > /bar
echo $?
```

Here is the output:

```
$ sh test1.sh 
test.sh: 3: test.sh: cannot create /bar: Permission denied
```

However, if the *echo* command is a part of a compound list, the execution continues after the failing command and prints the exit code:

```
set -o errexit

{ echo foo; } > /bar
echo $?
```

Here is the output:

```
$ sh test2.sh 
test.sh: 3: test.sh: cannot create /bar: Permission denied
2
```

How come the script doesn't abort? On the other hand, if I change the curly braces to parentheses it works like how I would expect.

Comment: My guess is that the key point is that it's the redirection causing the error, not the command itself, and that `bash` is treating the *source* of the error (simple command vs compound command) differently. In the latter case, the shell itself, and not the compound command, is "to blame", so `errexit` doesn't apply.

Comment: The line between intended and unintended effect of the `errexit` option is quite fine, one reason its use is not encouraged.

Comment: hey @chepner take a look at [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01), maybe you can decipher it and tell if it has anything to do with the behaviour op faced

Comment: Ah, likely. `bash` chooses to not exit, which appears to be the direction POSIX is leaning towards according to the footnote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX specification states that [a shell "may exit" if a redirection error occurs with a compound command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01).

`bash` chooses to exit if the compound command is a subshell command (`(...)`), but otherwise chooses not to. I am not aware of the rationale for this distinction; it may be historical in nature.

`set -e` has many quirks, and often will not behave the way you expect. Many people advise that you simply not use it.