# What does "-xe" with Shebang (#!/bin/bash) in Shell Script stand for?

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

I have copied a shell script and it is pretty much simple but on the first line with shebang, the `-xe` flag is specified.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
```

Can anyone explain what does it do? I have searched but could not find any helping material.

Comment: U could just try! Write a small  `Hello World'` script with this options in shebang, run them, then whipe options and try again!!

Comment: The bash options are documented in the bash man-page under the `set` command, section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_.  The reason is that you could alternatively have written in your code `set -x; set -e`.

Comment: It's the combination of (singleletter) options `-e` = exit if any command execution returns nonzero status except in a context that handles such: `while until if && || !` and `-x` = print commands as they are executed. Do `help set` or see the doc for `set` e.g. online at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html . (The run-command supports all `set` singleletter options plus a few others not relevant to your Q.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is adding shell options to the shebang:

- `-x`, `-o xtrace`: Trace display executed statements.
- `-e`, `-o errexit`: Exit on error, but inconsistently for legacy POSIX compliance.

```bash
#!/bin/bash -xe
```

This shebang setting combines two discouraged bad practices with their own set of issues:

1. First bad practice is setting shell options in the shebang; because it means they will be ignored when invoking the script directly with: `bash script_name`, rather than making the script file executable, and invoking `./script_name`.
   Options shall be set explicitly in code with `set -x`, or preferably use their more straightforward long name (example: `set -o xtrace` instead of `set -x`).
2. Second bad practice is using the `-e` option or `set -o errexit` which is only there for legacy POSIX compliance, but acts so inconsistently in different situations; that it causes more bugs than it avoids.

Here are some references about those `set -e`, `set -o errexit` quirks and issues:

- [BashPitfalls § 60.1. errexit - Greg Wooledge](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#errexit)
- [Why doesn't sh with errexit work with a command list? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175244/why-doesnt-sh-with-errexit-work-with-a-command-list)

Comment: Would be nice to have an example of what _inconsistency_ means in this case.

Comment: @enlico added references to the `errexit` issues.